# Android library ChatKit not display images

Tags: android, chatkit

I want display image file after sent. But result is empty message and is displayed on the left side of screen(received side).
This happens with any url set.

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXsGj.png)

My `item_list.xml`:

```xml
<com.stfalcon.chatkit.messages.MessagesList
        android:id="@+id/chat.room.messagesList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chat.room.input" />
```

My adapter:

```java
adapter = new MessagesListAdapter<ChatMessage>(getMyChatUser().getId(), null);
        messagesList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

or

```
adapter = new MessagesListAdapter<ChatMessage>(getMyChatUser().getId(), imageLoader);
        messagesList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

with ImageLoader

```
imageLoader = new ImageLoader() {
            @Override
            public void loadImage(ImageView imageView, @Nullable String url, @Nullable Object payload) {
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(imageView);
            }
        };
```

My attachments:

```java
messageInput.setAttachmentsListener(new MessageInput.AttachmentsListener() {
   @Override
   public void onAddAttachments() {
      ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt()), null, getMyChatUser());
      chatMessage.setImage(urlImage);
      adapter.addToStart(chatMessage, true);
   }
});
```

`ChatMessage` implements `MessageContentType.Image`
as the official guide says.

**Solution**
Implementation is right. I passed the wrong URL format

Answer (score 1):

**Few notes**

This is the constructor when you want your adapter to contain image/s.

```java
MessagesListAdapter<Message> adapter = new MessagesListAdapter<T>(senderId, imageLoader);
messagesList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

More on `MessageListAdapter.java`:

```java
/**
 * For default list item layout and view holder.
 *
 * @param senderId    identifier of sender.
 * @param imageLoader image loading method.
 */
public MessagesListAdapter(String senderId, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
   this(senderId, new MessageHolders(), imageLoader);
}
```

**What went wrong**

You are passing `null` on the constructor

```java
adapter = new MessagesListAdapter<ChatMessage>(getMyChatUser().getId(), null);
        messagesList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> If the method returns null, the adapter recognizes the message as a text message and displays it in the appropriate form. If the url of the image is present, an image will be displayed using ImageLoader, which we passed to the adapter.

**What you can do**

Create something like this[1] and pass it to the `MessageListAdapter`

```java
ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader() {
   @Override
   public void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url) {
       Picasso.with(MessagesListActivity.this).load(url).into(imageView);
   }
};
```

**Read more on**

- [1] https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/docs/IMAGE_LOADER.md
- https://github.com/stfalcon-studio/ChatKit/blob/master/docs/COMPONENT_MESSAGES_LIST.md#adding-image-message

Comment: thanks. I tried implementing this way before but the result is the same. Now the question to be more complete

Comment: I think you may have found the answer yourself :)